# SOQL field/object security setting in all Permission Set

Tags: soql, profile, permission-sets

I have two questions:

1. How to get all Permission Sets' Name/Label?
2. How to know the Security setting in a name-knowed Permission Set?

Scenario:

For audit reason, I have to retrieve Object/Field read/edit Security, programatically.

Regular Security Setting/Profile, could be retrieve via sqol as:

```
SELECT ID, SObjectType, ParentId, PermissionsCreate , PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete
    From ObjectPermissions
    where SObjectType = 'Account'
            AND ParentId IN ( Select id 
                    FROM PermissionSet
                    WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' )
```

And I've learned Permission sets are related to an user via PermissionSetAssignment.

Such as:

```
SELECT PermissionSet.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Name, Assignee.ProfileId
        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
        ORDER BY PermissionSet.Name
```

But I don't know how to combined these soql to get security setting in a permission set.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure about what you are asking due to your explanation. But,

> How to get all Permission Sets' Name?

Use this query:

```
Select Id, Name From PermissionSet
```

> How to know the Security setting in a name-knowed Permission Set?

Use something like:

```
SELECT ID, SObjectType, ParentId, PermissionsCreate , PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete
    From ObjectPermissions
    where SObjectType = 'Account'
            AND ParentId IN ( Select id 
                    FROM PermissionSet
                    WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'XXX' )
```

Judging by your description, if you know the assignee's Id and want to find out the related permission set's permission:

```
SELECT ID, SObjectType, ParentId, PermissionsCreate , PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete
    From ObjectPermissions
    where SObjectType = 'Account'
            AND ParentId IN ( Select PermissionSetId 
                    FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                    WHERE Assignee.Id = 'XXX' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!  The first soql is really useful once I've add `Lable` in it: `Select Id, Name, Label From PermissionSet`